# Jackson - deserialize json into generic type

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a model that looks like this:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class InputMessage<T> {

    @JsonProperty("UUID")
    private String UUID;

    @JsonProperty("MessageType")
    private String messageType;

    @JsonProperty("KeyData")
    private T keyData;

    ...

    getters/setters
}
```

This will be in a library that will be called from arbitrary clients, so the KeyData field has a generic type. If I try to make a call like the following from the client code, I get a ClassCastException `java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class model.KeyData`:

---

**Edit** :

Try with `constructParametricType()` advise but always an error.

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JavaType type = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(InputMessage.class, KeyData.class);
KeyData keyData = objectMapper.readValue(inputMessage.getKeyData().toString(), type);
```

The json that I'm attempting to deserialize looks like this:

```
{
  UUID: 9bae9a6a-5553-4716-8a85-995f36df7732,
  KeyData: {
    CNSM_ID: 2,
    LGCY_SRC_ID: 123,
    PARTN_NBR: 1,
    PCD_EFF_DT: 2019-01-01,
    SRC_CD: AB
  },
  MessageType: provider_selection,
  Partition: 3,
  Rows: [
    {
      Type: l_cov_prdt_pcd_w_srch,
      SchemaID: 2,
      Value: base64encoded value
    }
  ]
}
```

The library I'm using to deserialize the json is com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `T` with Object? Does it works, Or you just need generic way works?

Comment: Show us how you deserialize the json.

Comment: I did try replacing T with Object and I get the ClassCastException when I try casting it to a KeyData object.

Comment: Which version of `Jackson` do you use? Could you post an example `JSON` you want to deserialise?

Comment: Using Jackson databind version 2.9.8. Example JSON to be deserialized added to original question. Thanks.

Comment: Please the next time, don't modify the question with the provided answer (`constructParametricType` usage) because it makes the overall post complicated to understand. You can add an edit section to makes it clearer. I edit to show the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you deserialize a JSON to a generic class, Jackson cannot guess the generic type used since that is not an information present in the JSON.
And when it doesn't know how to deserialize a field, it uses a `java.util.LinkedHashMap` as target.

What you want is a generic type such as :

```
InputMessage<KeyData> inputMessage = ...;
KeyData keyData = inputMessage.getKeyData();
```

An elegant way to solve that is defining a Jackson `JavaType` for the class by specifying the expected generic.
[TypeFactory.constructParametricType(Class parametrized, Class... parameterClasses)](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeFactory.html#constructParametricType(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class...)) allows that.

Supposing you want to deserialize to `InputMessage<KeyData>`, you can do :

```
JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(InputMessage.class, KeyData.class);
InputMessage<KeyData> keyData = mapper.readValue(json, type);
```

About your comment :

> The library code with the generic type knows nothing about the
>   KeyData class, so I assume it belongs in the client code?

The library doesn't need to know this class but clients should however pass the class to perform correctly the deserialization and to return a generic instance to the client and not a raw type.

For example, clients could use the library in this way :

```
InputMessage<KeyData> inputMessage = myJsonLibrary.readValue("someValueIfNeeded", KeyData.class);
```

Comment: It's not clear to me where this code should go. The library code with the generic type knows nothing about the KeyData class, so I assume it belongs in the client code?

Comment: I updated with some explanation and by providing an example that should more stick to your usage.

Comment: I created a JavaType (`JavaType type = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(InputMessage.class, KeyData.class);`, but when I call readValue with the type (`objectMapper.readValue(inputMessage.getKeyData().toString(), type);`), I still get a ClassCastException. getKeyData() returns a HashMap, so I assume that's the issue?

Comment: @user1866924 insted of `readValue` you can use `mapper.convertValue(inputMessage, javaType)` this way object will be created and filled by the names of attributes insted of casting and missing attributes from `LinkedHashMap` will be set to nulls

Comment: Changing the code to use convertValue instead of readValue throws an IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized field \"CNSM_ID\" (class model.KeyData), not marked as ignorable (8 known properties: \"consumerId\", \"dentistEffectiveDate\", \"partitionNumber\", \"sourceCode\", \"physicianEffectiveDate\", \"providerId\", \"legacySourceId\", \"coverageTypeCode\"])". I'm not sure why it's not liking the CNSM_ID property, since it's defined in the KeyData class using the JsonProperty annotation: @JsonProperty("CNSM_ID")

Comment: Does the JsonProperty annotation get ignored when using convertValue?

Comment: I replaced the Jackson library package from org.codehaus.jackson to com.fasterxml.jackson, and now I'm back to the `java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.optum.exts.common.mapper.model.InputMessage cannot be cast to class model.KeyData ` exception when deserializing the InputMessage. Should I be importing from org.codehaus.jackson instead of com.fasterxml.jackson?

Comment: Sorry I edited without reviewing my code.  I didn't use the correct type. That should be `InputMessage<KeyData> keyData = mapper.readValue(json, type);`. I updated.